# jwrapper splash screen shrinks splash image

Tags: splash-screen, jwrapper

We have an image with a blue background that we use for a splash screen above the jwrapper splash logo, however, when jwrapper builds the exe, the logo is slightly shrunk and there is a white border around it. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour, JWrapper allows you to use any image and will rescale it to fit the splash dialog size.  There isn't currently any way to specify a different size of splash dialog.